# How to apply custom font, under line some part of text and make it clickable?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am struggling with this issue since 1 day. I want to apply custom font(in xml i am adding as fontFamily) to a textview. And also add apply underline for specific words in that textview with hyperlink and custom color.

I tried multiple ways like HTML text with **Html.fromHTML()**, Custom textview with **Paint()**,  **SpannableBuilder** etc. Everytime either I can apply underline with clickable link and without custom font **or** I can apply only custom font but not underline(In some devices like Samsung, Motorola etc devices only).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally achieved my requirement using [AwsomeTextHandler-Github](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1554) library.

Answer (score 0):

I use SpannableStringBuilder to make part of the string Bold, Underline, Clickable, etc.

```
val spannable = SpannableStringBuilder("My String to Underline")
val span = StyleSpan(Typeface.UNDERLINE)
// 14 is the start position and 22 is the end position
spannable.setSpan(span, 14, 22,Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
```

To create a link.

```
val clickableSpan: ClickableSpan = object : ClickableSpan() {
                override fun onClick(widget: View) {
                    // Do Something
                }
            }
spannable.setSpan(clickableSpan, <Start Position>, <End Position>, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
           
// Change the color
spannable.setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorBlack)), <Start Position>, <End Position>, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
// Make it Bold
spannable.setSpan(StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), <Start Position>, <End Position>, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
```

Comment: Thanks for response. I also tried SpannableStringBuilder. With this I can't achieve custom font, underline and clickable text at same time. Either I can apply custom font or underline.